# How can I treat a "empty cluster" warning, in K-means function?

Tags: r, error-handling, warnings, k-means

I'm searching for a solution to treat a warning message, from the `Kmeans` function of `amap` package. The warning message is the following:

`empty cluster: try a better set of initial centers`.

Is there anyway I could get a signal, so could know when this error message thrown, and then handle the problem? (e.g: running the algorithm until the there is the return has no empty cluster)

It is quite hard to make a nice reproducible example for me. But, I came with this ugly, but functional:

```
library(amap)

numberK = 20
ts.len = 7

time.series <- rep(sample(1:8000, numberK, replace = TRUE),ts.len)
time.series <- rep(rbind(time.series, time.series), 30)
time.series <- matrix(time.series, ncol = ts.len)

centers <- matrix( sample(1:3000, numberK*ts.len), ncol = ts.len)

Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)
```

If you run this on you terminal, it might send you the warning message I'm talking about.

**Note:** *My thoughts of solving this problem is catching the signal of the warning, and then execute the solution. However, I have no idea how can I possibly do that*

Comment: One option: `options(warn = 2); tryCatch(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},error = function(e) "Caught error")`.

Comment: Or with the default options: `tryCatch(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},warning = function(e) "Caught warning")`

Comment: ...or with warnings as errors, `attempt <- try(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},silent = TRUE)` and then check the class of `attempt` and branch off that.

Comment: I've got to say that I absolutely loved the last suggestion. Thank you a lot. This topic is closed. Feel free to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?options` (scrolling down a long ways to find `warn`...):

> sets the handling of warning messages. If warn is negative all
>   warnings are ignored. If warn is zero (the default) warnings are
>   stored until the top–level function returns. If 10 or fewer warnings
>   were signalled they will be printed otherwise a message saying how
>   many were signalled. An object called last.warning is created and can
>   be printed through the function warnings. If warn is one, warnings are
>   printed as they occur. If warn is two or larger all warnings are
>   turned into errors.

So using `tryCatch` you can specify a `warning` handler function to do stuff upon catching a warning:

```
> tryCatch(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},
         warning = function(e) "Caught warning")
[1] "Caught warning"
```

Or you can set all warnings to be escalated to errors via:

```
options(warn = 2)
```

as described in the docs. Then,

```
> tryCatch(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},
           error = function(e) "Caught error")
[1] "Caught error"
```

Although many people seem to prefer `tryCatch`, I often like the explicitness of `try`, which feels easier to me if I want to do some sort of `if...else` block after running the expression:

```
options(warn = 2)
attempt <- try(expr = {Kmeans((time.series), centers = centers, iter.max = 99)},silent = TRUE)
> class(attempt)
[1] "try-error"
```

So then you can check `class(attempt)` in an `if` statement (the preferred way is to check `inherits(attempt,"try-error")`) and do stuff accordingly.